# How can I download a image from a url, and post the loaded image to an exist api?

Tags: ruby, ajax, post

I want to get the value of a URL from an input tag, then do an ajax post, download the image from the URL, and the post the loaded image to an exist API (an API only support post files).

This is what I have so far:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="formSubmit" method="post" target="1">
      <input id="urlInput" type="text" name="url" placeholder="Please input url of picture.">
</form>

<button class="submitBtnUrl"></button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.submitBtnUrl').on('click', function() {
    $('#formSubmit').submit(function(event) {
        searchClothesUrl();
        return false;
    });
});

function searchClothesUrl(url){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/search_clothes_url',
        data: {
            'url': /url
        },
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data){

            };
        }
    })
};

post '/url' 
do
    halt 400 unless params[:url]

    =begin
    How can i do to submit the loaded image to the api?
    =end

    payload = {
        :upload => File.new(fn, 'rb')
    }
    result = JSON.parse RestClient::Request.execute(:method => :post,
        :url => 'http://api',
        :payload => payload)
    result.to_json
end
```